# Azure AI Translator : How does Translator count characters?

Tags: azure-ai-translator

Translator counts every code point defined in Unicode as a character. Each translation counts as a separate translation, even if the request was made in a single API call translating to multiple languages. The length of the response doesn't matter and the number of requests, words, bytes, or sentences isn't relevant to character count.

Translator counts the following input:

- Text passed to Translator in the body of a request.
- Text when using the Translate, Transliterate, and Dictionary Lookup methods
- Text and Translation when using the Dictionary Examples method.
  All markup: HTML, XML tags, etc. within the request body text field. JSON notation used to build the request (for instance the key "Text:") is not counted.
- An individual letter.
- Punctuation.
- A space, tab, markup, or any white-space character.